# Javascript class toggling

Tags: javascript

I have made a function which toggles different classes:

```
var input = document.getElementById("input-collapse");
var y = document.getElementById("toggler1");
var z = document.getElementById("toggler1-close");

function toggler1(input) {;
    if (!x.style.display || x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "inline-block";
        y.style.display = "none";
        z.style.display = "flex";
        input.className = "animated fadeInLeft"
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
        y.style.display = "flex";
        z.style.display = "none";

        input.classList.remove("fadeInLeft")
        input.classList.toggle("fadeOutLeft")
    }

}
```

On the first click, button `var y` shoves an input element (`display: flex;`). It also closing button (`var z`). Everything works fine until hitting that close button. Class `fadeOutLeft` doesn't work the same way as `fadeInLeft` works. Input element dosen't fade out to left. It just disappears with `display: none;` rule.

What can I do to make input element fade out left when triggering close button event?

I'm learning js and this is an exercise.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to hide the element *after the animation finished* (e.g. by using a timeout) while you need to show the element *before the animation starts*.

Comment: [Controlling CSS Animations and Transitions with JavaScript | CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/)

Comment: @JonasWilms 

Can you tell me if this is a good example:

 setTimeout(function() {
        while (x.style.display === "inline-block") {
            x.className = "animated fadeOutLeft";
            x.classList.remove("fadeInLeft")
        }
    }, 5000)